# Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger, for a merge-commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

I am trying to generate a webhook from Github to trigger a build whenever a feature branch gets merged to the specific branch (e.g. `master`). I am using the "[Generic Webhook Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)" plugin in Jenkins to do this since couldn't find any other suitable plugins.

And I found I could refer to two variables in the payload.

- `payload.ref` == "refs/head/master"
- `payload.commits[1].message` matches `Merge pull request*`

However, in the plugin, it seems that I could set only one filter. Is there any way to set multiple filters?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by using the `regexpFilterExpression`.

First you will need to put the branch name for which the push event came for into a variable named `ref` by adding this to the `GenericTrigger` class:

```
genericVariables: [
    [key: 'ref', value: '$.ref']
]
```

Now we need all the titles from the commits that were in the trigger payload, so add another variable for it

```
,[key: 'commit_titles', value: '$.commits[*].title']
```

Then we need to assemble the string on which the filter will be applied on by defining the `regexpFilterText` property in `GenericTrigger` class

```
...
regexpFilterText: 'BRANCH: $ref COMMIT_TITLES: $commit_titles END',
...
```

Variables will be substituted.

Then it is time to define the actual filter

```
...
regexpFilterExpression: "BRANCH: refs/heads/master COMMIT_TITLES: .*?(Merge pull request).*? END"
...
```

Complete example:

```
properties ([
    pipelineTriggers([
        [$class: 'GenericTrigger',
            genericVariables: [
                [key: 'ref', value: '$.ref'],
                [key: 'commit_titles', value: '$.commits[*].title']
            ],
            token: 'my secret token',
            causeString: 'Triggered because of $commit_titles in branch $ref',
            printContributedVariables: true,
            printPostContent: true,
            silentResponse: false,
            regexpFilterText: 'BRANCH: $ref COMMIT_TITLES: $commit_titles END',
            regexpFilterExpression: "BRANCH: refs/heads/master COMMIT_TITLES .*?(Merge pull request).*? END"
        ]
    ])
])
```